# Can not reach final if inside function

Tags: javascript

Hello I have to validate a number and I have a function for it that was translated from another language to javascript. The first two if conditions work but I can not reach the final if. I tried inserting a correct and an incorrect number and it does not reach the final if.

Can someone tell me why can I not reach the final if ?

```js
function strReverse(str) {
  var splitext = str.split("");
  var revertext = splitext.reverse();
  var reversed = revertext.join("");
  return reversed;
}

function validCUI() {
  var v = document.getElementById("cui").value;

  if (v.length < 2 || v.length > 10) {
    alert("Numarul de caractere ale Codului Unic de Identificare trebuie sa fie intre doua si 10 caractere");
    document.getElementById("cui").value = "";
  }

  if (v.charAt(0) === "0") {
    alert("Primul caracter al unui Cod Unic de Identificare nu poate fi 0(zero)!\n\nCorectati valoarea introdusa...");
    document.getElementById("cui").value = '';
  }
  alert("xxx");
  var key = "753217532";
  key = strReverse(key);

  var cuirev = strReverse("" + v.valueOf());
  var control = cuirev.substring(0, 1);
  cuirev = cuirev.substring(1);

  var length = cuirev.length;
  var suma = 0;
  alert("inainte de for");
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    suma += parseInt(cuirev.charAt(i), 10) * parseInt(key.charAt(i), 10);
  }
  alert("dupa for");
  suma *= 10;
  alert("inainte de final");
  if ((((suma % 11) == 10) && (control == "0")) || (((suma % 11) != 10) && ((suma % 11).toString() == control))) {
    alert("CUI corect");
  } else {
    alert("CUI incorect");
    document.getElementById("cui").value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="cui" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" onclick="validCUI()" value="validate" />
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to make it a [mcve]

Comment: Change `function strReverse(v) {` to `function strReverse(str) {`

Comment: Voting to close as typo. The error was fixed editing the snippet. You can delete the question

Comment: @mplungjan Why did you fix problem inside question?

Comment: @EzioMercer Because it should be noted by OP and deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always check your console for errors first!

```
function strReverse(v){
        var splitext = str.split("");
        var revertext = splitext.reverse();
        var reversed = revertext.join("");
        return reversed;
}
```

Here, for example you use `str` while the argument of the function is `v`, I suppose you meant `v.split('');`

Comment: No he meant `str.split` and `strReverse(str)` - please do not answer typo-type questions

Comment: It was not a typo, but using an undefined variable. You can may call it typo when he define function as `strReverse(str)` and write `srt.split()`. Also, how do you know what he ment?:) Usually ppl write `function strReverse(v)` _before_ the function body, so in that case, the 'typo' was `str`:P

Comment: `typo-type`  - op meant to use str in the function and v when calling it but typed v instead of str: typo-type. USELESS to anyone else searching SO for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Change `var splitext = str.split("");` to this `var splitext = v.split("");`

Comment: No he meant `str.split` and `strReverse(str)` - please do not answer typo-type questions

Comment: @mplungjan Why did you decide what he meant? He didn't say anything about it. And why I should not answer this type of questions?

Comment: Because they are worthless to anyone else than OP. It should be marked as typo and deleted

Comment: And what *I* meant, is you pass the var to the function but use a generic variable name IN the function. `v` is the value he reads, `str` is what he tests. A much better name in a function  that does string manipulation

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for explanation! I didn't have "typo" flag. May be there is another "name" in flags list?

Comment: __**Not reproducible or was caused by a typo** While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: @mplungjan It is in "Close" section which I don't have yet :)